# Convergence in probability, Y$X_n$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling with the following problem

a) Show that if $X_n \overset{p}\to X$ (convergence in probability) and $Y$ any random variable $X_nY \overset{p}\to XY$

b) Find a case where the previous result isn't true if we change convergence in probability by convergence in distribution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a), direct method:

For any $c > 0$, you can show $$P(|X_n Y - X Y| > \epsilon, |Y| \ge c)  \to 0.$$

Fix $\delta > 0$. For an appropriately chosen $c > 0$, we have
$$P(|X_n Y - XY| > \epsilon) 
\le P(|X_n Y - XY| > \epsilon, |Y| \ge c)  + P(0 < |Y| < c)
\le \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$$
for all large $n$.

---

a), alternate method:

[The random vector $(X_n, Y)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ in probability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB4) Thus by the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Statement) applied to this random vector, $X_n Y  \overset{p}{\to} XY$.

---

b): Let $X$ be a nonzero symmetric random variable, and let $X_n := -X$ and $Y := X$. We have $X_n \overset{d}{\to} -X$ because $X$ is symmetric. However, $X_n Y = -X^2$ while $X Y = X^2$.